# How to install tidy module in my amazon linux 2 package

Tags: php-8, tidy, amazon-linux-2, php-8.2

I am getting below error of  `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "tidy" not found in`

From this below line of code

```
// Tidy
$tidy = new \tidy();
```

Before it was working for php5 version, recently we have been upgraded to php8.2 since then its not working

Since we are using amazon linux 2 we didn't find tidy package available there.
these below packages available in my system

```
jtidy.noarch                                          2:1.0-0.16.20100930svn1125.amzn2                                   amzn2-core
jtidy-javadoc.noarch                                  2:1.0-0.16.20100930svn1125.amzn2                                   amzn2-core
perltidy.noarch                                       20121207-3.amzn2                                                   amzn2-core
```

I tried installing jtidy by using command of `yum install jtidy`

It says package installed successfully, still i am getting same error
Can someone help me out where i did wrong.